# Powershell ISE throws RemoteException when working to GitLabRunner

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, powershell-remoting

I am trying to stop GitlabRunner windows service using powershell. When I execute the command in elevated powershell prompt, I see the following expected response
[image]

Now if I run the same command in powershell ISE as Administrator It shows RemoteException error.

[image]

Note that the service is actually getting sopped even if the response shows error.
I get the same kind of error response with girlab-runner's other commands like `register` or `start`. Commands are working but shows error in response and only happens in ISE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is that your `gitlab-runner.exe` call sends its output to *stderr*, not stdout.

Unfortunately, **the ISE  *inappropriately* renders stderr output from external programs as *PowerShell errors***, which is what you saw;
a simple way to provoke the symptom is to run `cmd /c 'echo to stderr >&2'`

The **workaround** is:

```bash
.\gitlab-runner.exe 2>&1 | % ToString  # % is short for ForEach-Object
```

- `2>&1` is a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) that merges stderr output into the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), PowerShell's stdout equivalent.
- Converting the resulting stream of lines to *strings* (with `% ToString`) is necessary, because PowerShell wraps stderr lines in [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances.

---

However, you can **avoid the need for workarounds by migrating away from the obsolescent ISE**:

- The Windows PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).
- The actively developed, cross-platform and cross-edition editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).